# pandas compare 1 row value with every other row value and create a matrix

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, matrix

DF in hand
[image]

Steps I want to perform:

1. compare A001 data with A002, A003,...A00N
2. for every value that matches raise a counter by 1
3. do not increment the count if NA
4. repeat for row A002 with all other rows
5. create a matrix using the index with total count of matching values
   DF creation:

> data = {'name':['A001', 'A002', 'A003',
> 'A004','A005','A006','A007','A008'],
> 'Q1':[2,1,1,1,2,1,1,5],
> 'Q2':[4,4,4,2,4,2,5,4]
> 'Q3':[2,2,3,2,2,3,2,2]
> 'Q4':[5,3,5,2,3,2,4,5]
> 'Q5':[2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2]}
>
> df = pd.DataFrame(data)

> df.at[7, 'Q3'] = None

desired output
[image]

thanks in advance.

Comment: Could put your data as code using `pd.DataFrame(....)` ?

Comment: @Carmoreno I just added the data, my apologies for not including them in the start

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IIUC,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'name':['A001', 'A002', 'A003', 'A004','A005','A006','A007','A008'], 
                   'Q1':[2,1,1,1,2,1,1,5], 
                   'Q2':[4,4,4,2,4,2,5,4], 
                   'Q3':[2,2,3,2,2,3,2,2], 
                   'Q4':[5,3,5,2,3,2,4,5], 
                   'Q5':[2,2,3,2,2,2,2,2]})

dfm = df.merge(df, how='cross').set_index(['name_x','name_y'])

dfm.columns = dfm.columns.str.split('_', expand=True)

df_out = dfm.stack(0).apply(pd.to_numeric, errors='coerce').diff(axis=1).eq(0).sum(axis=1).groupby(level=[0,1]).sum().unstack()
```

output:

```
name_y  A001  A002  A003  A004  A005  A006  A007  A008
name_x                                                
A001       5     3     2     2     4     1     2     4
A002       3     5     2     3     4     2     3     3
A003       2     2     5     1     1     2     1     2
A004       2     3     1     5     2     4     3     2
A005       4     4     1     2     5     1     2     3
A006       1     2     2     4     1     5     2     1
A007       2     3     1     3     2     2     5     2
A008       4     3     2     2     3     1     2     5
```

Comment: Raises this error as the data set contains few null values
expected :
do not increment the count if NA
TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'int'
As seen in Q14 for A001

Comment: Looks like some of you answers. strings instead of numbers. include that NA value in your test data and I'll fixed the code.

Comment: I added NAN for A008 Q3

Comment: @Peaches just updated to again, added pd.to_numeric casting.